# get_comment_link without pagination base in the returned URL?

Tags: comments

On pages with paginated comments get_comment_link returns URLs in the following format:

```
http://samplesite.com/sample-page/comment-page-3/#comment-256
```

How could I make it return a URL like this?

```
http://samplesite.com/sample-page/#comment-256
```

Comment: If you're not using pagination, just disable it in Settings > Discussion.

Comment: I _am_ using pagination, it's a long story :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange that you want to use comments pagination where the comment links are without the comments pagination base.

But you can try this (untested):

```
/**
 * Remove the comments pagination base from comments links
 */

! is_admin() && add_filter( 'get_comment_link', function( $link, $comment, $args )
{ 
    if( $args['per_page'] )
        $link = sprintf( "%s#comment-%d",
            get_permalink( $comment->comment_post_ID ),
            $comment->comment_ID
        );
    return $link;
}, 10, 3 );
```

Another option would be to replace it with something like:

```
$link = preg_replace( '%comment-page-\d+/%', '', $link );
```

where the base could be dynamically fetched with:

```
global $wp_rewrite;
if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() )
    $comments_pag_base = $wp_rewrite->comments_pagination_base;
```

Comment: The first approach solved my problem just fine, and I have not yet noticed any issues with it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @pereyra you're welcome, glad to hear it worked for you.

Comment: It's not that strange. Wordpress does not provide a native way to show latest comments on the first page, sorted by most recent. Instead, it will oddly sort by latest on a per page basis but pages will be oldest to latest unless changed in code. This is opposite of most websites on the internet. The workaround requires effort but is a better user experience. Thanks for the tip!